# ElasticSearch filtering results according buckets length ( number of unique keys in a bucket)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to write down an elastic aggregation which only returns a key only if its inner bucket's length is greater than 1.

```
"aggs": {
    "product_definitions": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "definition_name",
            "size": 200,
            "exclude": "NO_MATCH",
            "min_doc_count": 5
        },
        "aggs": {
            "product_instances": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "data_source_name",
                    "size": 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my aggregation an it returns:

```
"aggregations": {
    "product_definitions": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 10,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 29281,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "DANA ANTRİKOT KG",
                "doc_count": 13,
                "product_instances": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "SariyerMarketCom",
                            "doc_count": 13
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "key": "Keskinoğlu Piliç Salam 700G",
                "doc_count": 10,
                "product_instances": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "HappyCenterComTr",
                            "doc_count": 9
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "SanalMarketComTr",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "key": "Doğuş Filiz Çayı 1000 G",
                "doc_count": 9,
                "product_instances": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "HappyCenterComTr",
                            "doc_count": 7
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "SanalMarketComTr",
                            "doc_count": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
       ]
    }
 }
```

I want keys in products definitions only if their product instances buckets has more than two keys. In this example it should only return 2. and 3. keys and not 1. because bucket of 1. key only contains 1 key which is

```
"buckets": [
              {
                  "key": "SariyerMarketCom",
                   "doc_count": 13
              }
            ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage the [`bucket_selector` pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) to achieve that, like this:

```
"aggs": {
    "product_definitions": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "definition_name",
            "size": 200,
            "exclude": "NO_MATCH",
            "min_doc_count": 5
        },
        "aggs": {
            "product_instances": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "data_source_name",
                    "size": 100
                }
            },
            "minimum_2": {
                "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                        "count": "product_instances._bucket_count" 
                    },
                    "script": "params.count >= 2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives the error
     "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
     "reason": "[script] unknown field [source], parser not found"

By the way I use elastic search version of 5.5

Comment: 5.5. OK. I've fixed my answer, please try again